# Export configurable product size attribute

Tags: php, magento, csv, feed

I have the following issue: I'm trying to build a product feed for a price comparison engine. My store sells clothes, and all my products are configurable. For example, the configurable product T Shirt is made up of 3 simple products, with the clothing size S, M and L.

My feed exports to a .csv file. There is one line for each configurable product. The problem is that i need a column called "size" which would include all the existing sizes of associated simple products (for example S|M|L).

I've tried several solutions like:

```
$prod_size = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

$prod_size = $product->getAttributeText('size');

$prod_size = $product->getData('size');

$prod_size = $product->getSize();
```

I use this statement to join the data from associated products to the configurable product:

```
if ($GROUPED_PRODUCT['prod_size'] != "") {
    $PRODUCT['prod_size'] = $GROUPED_PRODUCT['prod_size'];
}
```

Can anyone please lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all the attributes with their values for a configurable product.

```
$productAttributeOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}
print_r($attributeOptions);
```

Modify as per your need.